# Identity Server 4 No Security Token Validator available for token

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt, identityserver4

may somebody help me with this. In last few weeks I have been learning how to use Identity Server 4 and how to implement implicit flow by using Id4 as separate app, angular 4 as client (separate app) and asp.net core api as third one.

I managed to issue id and access tokens from id4 server, add access token into authorization header when I want to call api. But I am getting No SecurityTokenValidator available for token as error.

So what I did wrong?

I am using In Memory test data and AddDeveloperSigningCredential:
[image]

And on api side I get this:
[image]

I use UseJwtBearerAuthentication middleware on api side:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this at the end. I updated asp.net core to version 2 and added new AspNetCore Authentication JwtBearer middleware in Startup class of Api project and now everything works fine.

I will attach Startup class of my api project, maybe it can help to someone.

[image]

[image]